# Anyone who knows about tomatousb, which version will work for me?

Tags: wireless-router, tomato

I have a netgear wndr3400v3 wireless router. It has 64mb ram and 8mb flash.
I put tomatousb firmware on it. Currently I have

`Tomato Firmware 1.28.0000 MIPSR2-123 K26 USB WNDR`

The download file is

`tomato-K26USB-NVRAM64K-1.28.RT-N5x-MIPSR2-123-WNDR-WNDR3400v3.chk`

So i know to get USB, k26, mips2 and nvram64k.

But when I look at the [download list](http://tomato.groov.pl/download/K26/build5x-130-EN/), all I see is either mips2 with no nvram64k, or the ones that do have 64k are mips1.

I tried downloading the nocat vpn mips2 but that bricked my router. I tried the AIO mips2 and it said "too big to fit on mtd"

I'm starting to think my router just isnt supported for more than one build.

Any help?

Comment: Why don't you just keep what is currently working?

Comment: @Ramhound

My version doesnt have captive portal which I want.

Comment: TomatoUSB hasn't been updated in 5 years.  The fork you linked to does not support your router.  The firmware you linked to is it for your router, by the way, which hasn't been updated in 8 months ( in other words its been abandoned ).

Comment: There are loads of forks.  I was using the Toastman mod on my Netgear WNR3500L a few years ago, but he seems to have stopped.  Try the AdvancedTomato
GUI Mod, of your router has enough RAM.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato_(firmware)#Feature_comparison

Comment: You might want to consider DD-WRT, if your router is not supported (it probably is  if it is Broadcom chipset based), as it supports many more routers.